# reading textfile from url and populate in Gridview Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have codded for reading and textfile from url and populate in Gridview. The problem is the textfile has in first row splited by one space but in 2nd and 3rd row has many rows. How to populate in gridview below in my textfile and and C# code Txt file has data like this **`strong text`**

*

> strong text

*
Misdate ServiceName ProductName SubsCount   SubsRevenue RenewalCount    RenewalRevenue  TotalRev
20170310    PayPerUse   PayPerUse_ATN_News_VideoAlert   546 1110.81 0   0   1110.81 
20170311    PayPerUse   PayPerUse_ATN_News_VideoAlert   549 1063.23 0   0   1063.23

And the C# code to read and populate is

```
Stream data = client.OpenRead("my URL text File ");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Misdate."); //Misdate ServiceName ProductName SubsCount   SubsRevenue RenewalCount    RenewalRevenue TotalRev
            table.Columns.Add("ServiceName.");
            table.Columns.Add("ProductName");
            table.Columns.Add("SubsCount");
            table.Columns.Add("SubsRevenue");
            table.Columns.Add("RenewalCount");
            table.Columns.Add("RenewalRevenue");
            table.Columns.Add("TotalRev");
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data))

            //using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"E:\textfile\usss.txt"))
            {
                // string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //  List<string> parts = reader.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList();
                    string[] parts = reader.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                    // Response.Write(parts);
                    // table.Rows.Add(parts.ToString());
                    //string s = parts[0];
                   table.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]);
                }

            }
            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var newRow = table.NewRow();
for (int k=0; k<table.Columns.Count(); k++)
   newRow[k] = parts[k];

table.Rows.add(newRow);
```

Hope it will help